# Endomorphism ring which is not the endomorphism ring of an abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

> I have to find an example of a ring that can't be the endomorphism ring of an abelian group.

I am studying Fuchs, "Abelian groups", but I haven't seen such an example.
Does anyone have some references?

Comment: Here is a related MO question: [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32262/representation-of-rings)

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Krylov certainly includes a brief discussion of these in his [book](http://www.amazon.ca/Endomorphism-Rings-Abelian-Groups-Krylov/dp/1402014384) (Amazon link). But these rings aren't so exotic (necessarily). For example, the rings $\pmatrix{ \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ are such rings.

For a more elementary example, neither $\mathbb{F}_p^2$ nor $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ are endomorphism rings.  If they were, then the underlying ring should be an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space; but no vector space has those groups as its *only* endomorphisms.

Comment: Thanks mixedmath. But why those rings can't be the endomorphism ring of an abelian group ?

Comment: @stef: When I first studied about these rings, these were a natural result of a theorem or lemma (or something). I don't know how you've approached the subject, nor anything about Fuchs. So let me say a third - $\mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p$ is another such group. This is easier to see, as if it were End($G$), then $\mathbb{F}_p$ acts on $G$ and thus it would have to be an $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space - which it's not. Similarly, I suppose, $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ with $k > 1$ should work.