# Fields arising as endomorphism rings

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups

Do you know a field $K$ other than $F_p$ which is the endomorphism ring of an abelian group $G$?

I doubt that there is one because as $G$ gets bigger, $End(G)$ seems to be more and more noncommutative.

This question is inspired by my [previous request for examples of rings not arising as endomorphism rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254056/does-every-ring-with-unity-arise-as-an-endomorphism-ring).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is the endomorphism ring of $\mathbb{Q}$.