# How do you find all the functions of a cartesian product with the condition of it being a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Consider $R = \mathbb{Z}$ with the regular/standard addition +. With proof, find all functions ⊗ : R × R → R such that (R, +, ⊗) is a ring.

I understand cartesian products and that if $ R \text{ is } \mathbb{Z}, R \text{ x } R = \{\{r_1, r_1\} : r_1, r_2 \in R\} = \{\{z_1, z_2\} : z_1, z_2 \in  \mathbb{Z}\} $.

But how do I go about finding all the functions of it, when there isn't a an equation condition, I've never been faced with a question like this. The only condition is that it stays a ring, so aren't the possibilities never-endless or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Hint: $\otimes$ is completely determined by $1 \otimes 1$.

Comment: There are equation conditions. Since it's a ring, you know (for example) $a\otimes (b+c)=(a\otimes b)+(a\otimes c)$ for all $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very close relation between rings and endomorphisms of abelian groups.

If $R$ is a ring, then $(R,{+})$ is an abelian group.  Moreover: for each $r\in R$, the map $m_r(x)=rx$ is an endomorphism.  [The converse is *not* true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111348/endomorphism-ring-which-is-not-the-endomorphism-ring-of-an-abelian-group); but luckily you only need the forward direction.  Indeed, a stronger claim is true: the map $r\mapsto m_r$ is a homomorphism of abelian groups.

Your $(R,+)$ is fixed to be $R=\mathbb{Z}$, which has very few endomorphisms.  Can you classify all possible endomorphism groups that are quotients of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I just wanted to say that I think you might have accidentally deleted your answer to my recent question (about second degree curves). (if it was not accidental, please let me know and i will delete this comment)

Comment: @Aditya_math: It was not accidental.  I noticed a _very_ fatal flaw, and didn't want to leave the error in public while I fixed it.  (It's back now though!)